# How to change configuration of installed GDB in Ubuntu for cross debugging ARM-LINUX

Tags: linux, gdb, ubuntu-14.04

I have installed GDB using apt-get. The host and targets are  the same. I want to use it for cross debugging. Could anyone help out how to achieve this ?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: this might help:  http://www.stlinux.com/devel/debug/user/cross

Comment: Thanks, but I have come across this article before and it assumes that the GDB is already configured with --target=arm-none-linux-gnu,

Answer (score 1):

> The host and targets are the same. I want to use it for cross debugging.

You *can't*.

You need to build (or install a prebuilt one -- it's often included with your cross-compiler) a cross-gdb, and use *that* to perform cross-debugging.

Answer (score 1):

You should install gdb multiarch in ubuntu and gdbserver in the arm-linux target, that will allow you to remote debug programs in the arm target.

```
Example:

In the target:

target> gdbserver :2345 emacs foo.txt

In the ubuntu machine, start gdb and execute the command:

(gdb) target remote the-target:2345
```

See the manual for more details:
[Using the gdbserver program](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/gdbserver-man.html)